# ¿Como pasarle un objeto ya creado en una clase a otra?

Tags: java

Tengo una duda, estoy creando una aplicación de escritorio sencilla, la cosa es que cree un objeto de la clase "Gastos" la cual tiene 2 atributos nombre y valor; al objeto antes mencionado lo llame "gasto" y le asigne dos valores tomados por Jtextfield.

Código del  Botón que carga los datos:

```
public class GastosIngresos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private void BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    float  valorGasto;
    String nombreGasto;
    String variableAuxiliar;
    nombreGasto=this.JTextNombreGasto.getText();
    variableAuxiliar=this.JTextValorGasto.getText();
    valorGasto=Float.parseFloat(variableAuxiliar);
    Gastos **gasto** = new Gastos();
    **gasto**.setNombre(nombreGasto);
    **gasto**.setValor(valorGasto);    

    // Hasta acá va la carga y lo demás abre la pestaña nueva
    GastosIngresos obj=new GastosIngresos();
    obj.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}
```

Como se puede notar en el código superior a este mensaje creo un objeto de la clase Gastos y lo llamo "gasto", a este objeto le cargo dos datos los cuales son "nombre" y "valor", pero ahora necesito acceder a estos datos cargados en el objeto "gasto" en otra clase la cual es:

```
public class Extractos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private void BotonPrimerIngresoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Gastos gasto1 = new Gastos();

}
```

}

¿Como podria hacerlo?, ¿Cuando genero gasto1 no estoy creando todo el objeto de 0 y sin datos?.

Pdta: Edite para que sea mucho mas claro.

Comment: explicate mejor porque no te entinedo a ver tu tienes una clase gastos y un main? o una clase gastos otra clase y el main?y donde quieres que aparezca los datos de la clase gastos? pues lo primero necesitas crear los getter y setter de la clase para poder usarlo luego

Comment: Declaralo como atributo de clase y usa un getter

Comment: Hola, edite el post para tratar de ser mucho mas claro, espero haberlo logrado, un saludo y espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos formas de recibir el objeto.

**1º: Accedes al objeto**

Para acceder al objeto, necesitaras meterlo en un objeto estático.

```
public class GastosIngresos extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static Gastos gasto; //Creamos el objeto estatico

private void BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
  ...
  gasto = new Gastos();
  gasto.setNombre(nombreGasto);
  gasto.setValor(valorGasto);  

  ...
  }
 public static Gastos getGastos(){
  return gastos;
 }
}
```

Y luego en tu otra clase, accedes al objeto con la siguiente llamada:
`GastosIngresos.getGastos()`

**2º: Recibes el objeto**

La otra opcion es que la otra clase recibas el objeto. Puede ser mediante un constructor o seteando una variable estatica.

```
private void BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
  ...
  Gastosgasto = new Gastos();
  gasto.setNombre(nombreGasto);
  gasto.setValor(valorGasto);  

  //Usarias una de las dos lineas segun si es por constructor o variable estatica
  OtraClase otraClase= new OtraClase(gasto);
  OtraClase.setGasto(gasto);
  ...
  }
```

---

**MODIFICACIÓN**

Después de añadir el código de la segunda clase, optaría por la segunda opción (pero teniendo un setter estatico), aunque también seria valida la primera.

El código quedaría así:

```
private void BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
  ...
  Gastosgasto = new Gastos();
  gasto.setNombre(nombreGasto);
  gasto.setValor(valorGasto);  

  Extractos.setGasto(gasto);
  ...
  }
```

La otra clase seria así:

```
public class Extractos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  Gastos gasto1;
  private void BotonPrimerIngresoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   if(gasto1!=null)//Hacemos un nullcheck por si acaso aun no se ha seteado gasto1
   {
     //
     // TU CODIGO
     //
     gasto1=null;//Limpiamos la variable si no queremos que se use más
   }

 }
 public static void setGasto( Gastos gasto){
     gasto1=gasto;
 }
}
```

De esta forma, al activar el boton de `BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed`, automaticamente le mandara el objeto generado de tipo `Gastos` a la clase `Extractos`

Comment: No necesitas para nada que sea estatico en ninguno de los casos.

Comment: Si se tira por la opción de pasarle el objeto por el constructor, esta claro que no necesita los estáticos. Pero si el pulsar el botón, no va a desencadenar la ejecucion de la otra clase, entonces no se me ocurre otra forma de pasarle el objeto si no es por estático

Comment: Tal como lo tienes sin usar estatico funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Si llamas a `BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed.getGastos()` y se hace desde la clase que creo el objeto de la clase `GastosIngresos`, ciertamente no hace falta el estatic. Yo lo he hecho estático bajo el supuesto de que la segunda clase no es la que creo la clase `GastosIngresos`, por lo que si no es estatico, llamar a `getGastos()` devolveria null.

Comment: Hola, edite el post para tratar de ser mucho mas claro, espero haberlo logrado, un saludo y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Viendo que entre las dos clases no hay nigua relación del estilo "en una clase se crea el objeto que contiene la otra clase", optaría por la segunda opción (aunque la primera vale) Modifico respuesta para indicar como seria.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te entiendo pero creo que lo que quieres se hace así - creas **gasto** como dato miembro (field) de la clase **GastosIngresos**. Luego puedes acceder a **gasto** donde quieras. Algo así:

```
public class GastosIngresos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Gastos gasto;
    private void BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // ...
        gasto = new Gastos();
        // ... etc
    }
    // ... resto de clase
    void otroMetodo() {
        OtraClase oc = new OtraClase(gasto);// por ejemplo
        // ya lo tienes
    }
}
```

** EDITADO **
A ver @AlexanderLadino. Entiendo que entre las clases **GastosIngresos** y **Extractos** no hay ninguna relación. Entonces lo que se me ocurre es crear una clase singleton que puedes usar para transferir el objeto gastos entre las dos clases.

```
public class GastosHolder {

    private Gastos gasto;

    private GastosHolder() {}

    private static class Singleton {
        private static final GastosHolder INSTANCE = new GastosHolder();
    }

    public static GastosHolder getInstance() {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE;
    }

    public void setGastos(Gastos gasto) {
        this.gasto = gasto;
    }

    public Gastos getGasto() {
        return gasto;
    }

}
```

Y ahora desde **GastosIngresos**:

```
private void BotonAgregarOtroGastoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // ...
        Gastos gasto = new Gastos();
        // setters
        GastosHolder.getInstance().setGastos(gasto);
        // ... etc
```

}

Algo parecido desde **Extractos**:

```
Gastos gasto = GastosHolder.getInstance().getGastos();
```

También tienes el paquete *java.util.concurrent* por si te interesa estudiarlo un poco. Para el caso creo que lo que te propongo te va a funcionar.

Saludos

Comment: Hola, edite el post para tratar de ser mucho mas claro, espero haberlo logrado, un saludo y espero puedan ayudarme.