# ¿Como enviar datos de un JFrame a otro JFrame?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Estoy creando una aplicación en java en la cual tengo varios formularios JFrame creados, y tengo un arraylist en el jframe principal, los demás jframe tienen que rellenar este arraylist, el problema es que no se como enviar los datos de uno a otro

[image: Aqui esta la clase principal con el arraylist en donde debo introducir los datos]

[image: botón para llamar al método insertar para abrir un JFrame]

[image: Aquí el segundo JFrame con los datos que hay que introducir en el arraylist]

Aquí el segundo JFrame con los datos que hay que introducir en el arraylist

Comment: Podrias compartir lo que has intentado?

Comment: si ya están las imagenes

Comment: Todo lo que puedas compartir como código mejor que como imagen, asi se te podra ayudar mejor

Comment: Creo que lo mas sencillo sería pasar referencia del primer frame al segundo. En el primero te hace un método *setLoQueSea* y del segundo frame lo llamas.

Comment: Mira la respuesta que hice a esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263328/como-pasarle-un-objeto-ya-creado-en-una-clase-a-otra/263376#263376) . Es similar a lo que preguntas y te puede valer.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy sencillo, solamente tiene que acceder al objeto instanciado (primer`JFrame`) vendiéndoselo a través de constructor, y mediante `getters`, abastecerte de la información. No se si esa información pertenece a los atributos de un objeto, pero deberías crear el objeto en el segundo `JFrame` para posteriormente pasártelo a través de un `getter` del Array.

### Ventana 1

```
//Ventana principal
public class Ventana1 extends JFrame{

    ArrayList<Object> elementos = new ArrayList<Object>();

    //Evento que lanza la ventana con el formulario
    private void btnFormularioActionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
        Ventana2 ventana2 = new Ventana2(this);
        ventana2.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Accede al array list
    public ArrayList<Object> getArrayList(){
        return elementos;
    }
}
```

### VENTANA 2

```
//Ventana de formulario
public class Ventana2 extends JFrame{

    private Ventana1 v1;

    //Recibe por parametro la JFrame padre
    public Ventana2(Veenata1 parent){
        this.v1 = parent;
    }
    //Crea objeto con los campos relleno
    public Object getObject(){
        return new Object(txtField1.getText(), txtField2.getText(), ...);
    }
    //Evento que añade el objeto creado o datos al arraylist de la ventana 1
    private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
        v1.getArrayList().add(getObject());
   }
}
```