# como puedo pasar un dato que se encuentra en un Text Field de un jframe hijo que se abre desde un boton a un Text Field que se encuentra jframe padre

Tags: java

Java

de una ventana padre se abre mediante un botón otra ventana hijo, lo que se necesita es pasar información de la ventana hijo a la padre  de Text Field a Text Field

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como enviar datos de un JFrame a otro JFrame?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266469/como-enviar-datos-de-un-jframe-a-otro-jframe)

Comment: Esparcido, pero no me funcionó.

Comment: puedes editar tu pregunta agregandole exactamente que itentaste y que error te dio?

Comment: Disculpa si no me di a tender muy bien, en el software que estoy haciendo tengo un Jframe principal en el cual tengo un  botón y un campo Text Field que debe ser llenado con un dato que se obtendrá del cálculo que se hará en otro Jframe que se abrirá una vez sea presionado el botón