# ¿Cómo enviar los datos de un jframeform a otro jframeform (pero quiero que se muestre en la tabla del nuevo jframeform)?

Tags: java

```
package Modelo;//clase Cliente

import static Modelo.TomarPedido.contador;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public abstract class Cliente {
     private String Codigo;//registro de atencion 
     private String nom;
     private String tipodePago;
     //constructor
     public Cliente(){}
     
   

  
    

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getTipodePago() {
        return tipodePago;
    }

    public void setTipodePago(String tipodePago) {
        this.tipodePago = tipodePago;
    }
    public String getCodigo() {
        return Codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String Codigo) {
        this.Codigo = Codigo;
    }
    //metodos abstractos
    public abstract double PagoTotal();
    public abstract double Descuento();
    //metodos no abstractos
    public double PagoFinal(){
        return PagoTotal()-Descuento();
    }
    
     
    
     
     
    
    
}

//clase empleado

    package Modelo;
import Modelo.*;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;

public  class Empleado extends Cliente {
     private String nombres;
     private String mesa;
     private static int contador=0;
     
   
     public Empleado(){
         contador++;
         DecimalFormat df =new DecimalFormat("CLIE0000");
         super.setCodigo(df.format(contador));
                 
         
     }
    
  

    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }

    public String getMesa() {
        return mesa;
    }

    public void setMesa(String mesa) {
        this.mesa = mesa;
    }

    public static int getContador() {
        return contador;
    }

    public static void setContador(int aContador) {
        contador = aContador;
    }

   

    @Override
    public double PagoTotal() {
        return 0;
         }

    @Override
    public double Descuento() {
        return 0;
    }
     public Object[] Registro(){
        Object[] fila = {contador,super.getCodigo(),super.getNom(),
                        super.getTipodePago(),mesa,nombres,
                        Descuento(),PagoFinal()
                        };
        return fila;
    }

    
}
//Controlador del formulario
//esto nomalmente debe de ir en el formulario

    package Controlador;

import Modelo.Empleado;
import Procesos.ProcesosRdePedidos;
import Vista.frmRegistrodePedidos;
import Vista.frmVentanaLogin;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ControladorRdePedidos implements ActionListener{
    frmRegistrodePedidos vistargp;
    frmVentanaLogin Vistavl;
    DefaultTableModel modelo;
    
    public ControladorRdePedidos(frmVentanaLogin formab,frmRegistrodePedidos forma){
        this.vistargp = forma;
        this.Vistavl = formab;
      
        vistargp.btnActualizarTabla.addActionListener(this);
        Vistavl.btnRegistroPedidos.addActionListener(this);
        
        
        
        ActualizarTabla();
        IniciarForma();
        
    }
    void  ActualizarTabla() {
        String titulos[]={"Nro","Codigo","Categoria","Nombres"
                            ,"Pago Total",
                            "Descuento","Pago Final"        
                            };
       modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos)  ;
       vistargp.tbldatosR.setModel(modelo);

    }
    void IniciarForma() {
        vistargp.setTitle("Registro de Pedidos");
        vistargp.setVisible(true);
        vistargp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==vistargp.btnActualizarTabla ){
           Empleado emple= ProcesosRdePedidos.LeerEmpleado(Vistavl, vistargp);
           modelo.addRow(emple.Registro());
           ProcesosRdePedidos.LeerEmpleado(Vistavl, vistargp);
           
           
           
            
            
            
        }
    }
}

//esto va en el formulario 
    package Procesos;

import Modelo.Empleado;
import Vista.frmRegistrodePedidos;
import Vista.frmVentanaLogin;


public class ProcesosRdePedidos {
    
    public static void LimpiarEntradas( frmVentanaLogin frmvl,frmRegistrodePedidos frmrdp) {
        frmvl.cbxEmpleado.setSelectedIndex(0);
        frmvl.txtNombresCli.setText("");
        frmvl.txtNumMesa.setText("");       
        frmvl.cbxTipodePago.setSelectedIndex(0);
        frmvl.cbxEmpleado.requestFocus();
        
        
    }
    
    public static Empleado LeerEmpleado(frmVentanaLogin frmvl,frmRegistrodePedidos frmrdp){
      Empleado emp =new Empleado();
      emp.setNombres(frmvl.cbxEmpleado.getSelectedItem().toString());
      emp.setNom(frmvl.txtNombresCli.getText());
      emp.setMesa(frmvl.txtNumMesa.getText());
      emp.setTipodePago(frmvl.cbxTipodePago.getSelectedItem().toString());
      
      return emp;
        
    }

}
esto incia el programa 

package Main;

import Controlador.ControladorRdePedidos;
import Vista.frmRegistrodePedidos;
import Vista.frmVentanaLogin;


public class IniciarPrograma {

   public static frmVentanaLogin frmvl;
   public static frmRegistrodePedidos frmrdp;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frmvl=new frmVentanaLogin();
        
        ControladorRdePedidos cdpedidos = new ControladorRdePedidos(frmvl,frmrdp);
      
    }
        
}
```

La aplicacion se donde estan lo errores, lo que no sé hacer realmente es cómo mostrar los  datos del jframme form a la tabla de otro jframeform

Creo q el error está en el controlador de pedidos y en procesos
por que básicamente le he dicho al programa que se muestre en el frmventanaLogin pero que se muestre en una tabla, pero no funciona por que no le he dicho al programa que lo muestre en la tabla frmregistrodeperidos.

Si no lo pueden resolver por lo que tengo entendido es un problema dificil, desearía que me dejen como mandar los datos de un jframform a otra jframeform que tenga una tabla. Quiero que los datos que ponga en una ventana aparescan en otra ventana pero en una tabla. Además como correr el programa desde un java class main. Sólo desearia el codigo para q me den la idea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como enviar datos de un JFrame a otro JFrame?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266469/como-enviar-datos-de-un-jframe-a-otro-jframe)

Answer (score 0):

Debes de crear una función publica del tipo static que reciba los parámetros que quieres en el formulario de pedidos, luego en el formulario de registros de datos la mandas a llamar y le pasas los parámetros que deseas

Toma en cuenta que los valores que recibas en el formulario de pedido serán del tipo public static entonces tu tabla también tiene que serlo